# In Screen, how can I use 'F1' (function key) as my escape key?

Tags: gnu-screen

how can I use 'F1' (function key) as my escape key?

I have the following:

```
escape ``
```

I want to switch to use F1 as my escape, how can I do that?

Comment: Retagged, I believe you're referring to [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/)?

Answer (score -3):

you could use auto-it easy programming, www.autoitscript.com

hotkeyset('{f1}','esc')

func esc()
 send('{esc}')
endfunc

and if u dont want any icon down to the right just add #NoTrayIcon at the top of your code

Comment: The Asker asked for a method to change his GNU Screen escape-key to F1, not remap F1 to Esc.